# Uploading an Excel sheet and importing the data into SQL Server database with various number of columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, dynamic-columns

I am creating function to import the excel(.Xlsx) in SQL database through c# code and stored Procedure.

I'm using the following code on import button click.

public DataSet ImportExcelXLS(string FileName)
        {
            DataSet output = new DataSet();
            try
               {

```
            string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended 
            Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1\"";                          
            OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
            connExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            connExcel.Close();
            connExcel.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();            

             string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();                             
            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
            da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
            da.Fill(output);
            connExcel.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

and then converting excel to data table using following function.

```
public DataTable Convert_Commissionxlxs_toDataTable(string strFilePath)
    {
        ExL oExl = new ExL();
        FileUploadBO fileuploadBo_obj = new FileUploadBO();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = oExl.ImportExcelXLS(strFilePath, 0);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns["F" + i].ColumnName = fileuploadBo_obj.Get_ExcelColumnName(i);
        }  
            return dt;  
    }
```

after generating data table i am passing it to stored procedure as follows :

SQL Procedure code :

```
    ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_Save]  
(  

        @Trailing_Credit dbo.[TrailingCredit_Type]  readonly    
)
```

this code working fine.
in SQL server stored procedure i Used table valued parameter(user defined table).
but when my number of column in excel file changes then it throws an error that "you passed 20 parameter instead of 32".
how can I write the SQL procedure to accept any number of columns using table valued parameter.
or any other better way to do this.
Note :Number of columns in excel file get changes everyday.

Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend giving your Stored Procedure a different name. The `sp_` prefeix is reserved by Microsoft and means **S**pecial **P**rocedure. Using the prefix suggests it's a MS shipped object, and the prefix also results in a performance hit: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: As for your question, `dbo.TrailingCredit_Type` is a ***defined*** type; it can't have a variable number of columns. SQL objects require strict definitions, they **aren't** flexible.

Comment: yes , but what is the other way to do that, should i check for matching number of columns from table in c# and create data-table with those matched parameters only.

Comment: That would be one solution.